# How to have different spacing between items in the recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have a UiItemDecoration class that manages spacing.

```
public class UiItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int spanCount;//一行item数目
private int spacing;//item 之间的间隔
private boolean includeEdge;//边缘
private boolean includeTop;

public UiItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
    this.spanCount = spanCount;
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    this.includeTop = true;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
    outRect.left = 0;
    outRect.right = 10;
}
```

It works well when i want to have same spacing.shown in pictures below
 [image]
The problem is that i want different spacing between the items of the recyclerview
defined in class:

```
public class UiItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int spanCount;//一行item数目
private int spacing;//item 之间的间隔
private boolean includeEdge;//边缘
private boolean includeTop;

public UiItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
    this.spanCount = spanCount;
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    this.includeTop = true;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
    if (position%5 == 2){
        outRect.right = 30;
    }else {
        outRect.right = 5;
    }
    outRect.left = 0;
}
```

But the problem is that the item with position 2 is shrinking.
here is result：
[image]
Question:How to set the spacing between the items of the recyclerview

Comment: Are you using GridLayoutManager? I don't have a lot of experience with that one, but my brief experimentation makes it look like that layout manager does not play well with ItemDecoration offsets.

Comment: yes,it is GridLayoutManger. I think so, when the recyclerview measures the size of the item, it is evenly divided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the offsets, you can change the margins according to the position in **onBindViewHolder()** method of the adapter. If you are using RelativeLayout for creating your item layouts, then this code will work. Also adjusting the margins won't affect the view bounds of the items.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
    if (position%5 == 2){
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 0);
    }else {
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
    }
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: I tried the above method,but it still has no effect

Comment: the layout is still the same?

Comment: Yes, the same effect as setting the Decoration directly

Comment: did you remove `getItemOffsets()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {


    public static final int SPAN_COUNT = 4;


    private static final int DEFAULT_LEFT_OFFSET = 0;

    private static final int DEFAULT_RIGHT_OFFSET = 0;

    private static final int DEFAULT_TOP_OFFSET = 0;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_OFFSET = 0;


    private int mItemOffset;


    public ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
        mItemOffset = itemOffset;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Method to get offset for item views(child)
     *        and modifying all bounds- top, bottom, left and right for equal spacing.
     * @param outRect : Rect, the number of pixels in which a view should be inserted.
     * @param view : Views (child) which to be modified or decorated.
     * @param parent : Corresponding recycler view where decorations being applied.
     * @param state : Recycler view State state, contains focus, scroll etc info.
     */
    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        // column count fixed = 5

        if (position >= 0) {
            int column = position % SPAN_COUNT; // item column

            outRect.left = mItemOffset - column * mItemOffset / SPAN_COUNT;
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * mItemOffset / SPAN_COUNT;

            if (position < SPAN_COUNT) { // top edge
                outRect.top = mItemOffset;
            }
            outRect.bottom = mItemOffset; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = DEFAULT_LEFT_OFFSET;
            outRect.right = DEFAULT_RIGHT_OFFSET;
            outRect.top = DEFAULT_TOP_OFFSET;
            outRect.bottom = DEFAULT_BOTTOM_OFFSET;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using mItemOffset = -6 ;// modify with own

Don't forget

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), SPAN_COUNT);//columns
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemOffsetDecoration(SPACING));
```

Comment: Yes, this will make each item have the same spacing, but I think some of the spacing between items is different.